# Ember.js: Route-dependent Menu

Tags: ember.js

I've got a Template which defines an `<div id="sidemenu"><ul>...</ul></div>`.It should has some `<li>`-Elements which represents general available-Menu-Items. On Sub-routes I want to add some additional menu-entries which only make sense on that routes. But since the div where to put the li's into is defined in the parent-route-template, I don't know how I should implement this.

My first theoretical approach was to call a controller function which returns the necessary li's. I could override this function in each sub-controller but I don't know if this is good practice.

However I want to do it in a ember-vanilla way if possible (someone told me to use a plugin called "wormhole" or something)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would make the dependent portions of the menu a named outlet, then render into the outlet from each route's `renderTemplate` hook.

```html
{{! components/sidebar/template.hbs }}
<div id="sidemenu">
  <ul>
    <li>Generally available menu item 1</li>
    {{outlet name='nav'}}
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  </ul>
</div>
```

```js
// thing1/route.js
renderTemplate() {
    this.render('thing1-nav-template', {into: 'nav'});
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    this._super(...arguments);
}
```

You could use `{{ember-wormhole}}` I suppose--I don't know that module. It certainly does not fall into the category of "ember vanilla" if that's one of your criteria. Essentially, it would allow you to write the `thing1-nav-template` contents directly in your route template instead of another template. I have no idea how stable it is, so personally I'd do it the old-fashioned way using outlets; that's what they're there for.

Answer (score 2):

You can use https://github.com/yapplabs/ember-wormhole to render content from one template into an HTML element identified by an ID.

Menu Template:

```
<ul>
  <li>General stuff</li>
</ul>
<ul id='foobar' />
```

Subroute Template:

```
{{#ember-wormhole to="foobar"}}
  <li>Subroute stuff</li>
{{/ember-wormhole}}
```

Comment: Sounds like a good approach, indeed. Unfortunately, since ive got the requirement of doing it in an "ember vanilla"-way as already descriped in the main-question, this is no option for me. Thank you anyway!

Comment: Sorry, I obviously missed that requirement. OTOH addons are part of the Ember.js ecosystem and wormhole comes from Yapp labs, so it's closely tied to the core team. You could also copy the wormhole code to your repository as in-repo-addon.

Comment: Well, thats a good point. In that case, I will also check this approach too and evaluate it - under that point of view, it sounds like a very promising way. Thanks!